# Updating a field in multiple Airtable records at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, airtable

I'm working on an Airtable API integration, and I'm still totally new to this kind of thing... I'm pulling all the records in a specific view, doing stuff with the data, then updating a checkbox field on all those records to true. Problem is Airtable limits its api to 5 calls/second, and I'm not totally sure I'm sending the data correctly anyway.

```
function update_record(record_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/myAirtableBase/Table/' + record_id,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer apikey'
    },
    method: 'PATCH',
    data: {
      'fields': {
        'Checkbox Field': true
      }
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log('it worked! I think');
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('nope');
    }
  });
}

$('#check_printed_button').click(function() {
  var time = 0;
  $('.record-name').each(function() {
    var record_id = $(this).data('recordId');

    setTimeout(update_record(record_id, time), time);
    time += 250;
  });
});
```

Before this is done, I'm printing out each record in a table with its id in a data attribute.

My network pane shows that I get all the options requests back with a 200, but before the last few come back, I get a request method returned with a '429 Too Many Requests.' I tried to avoid that with the setTimeout and staggering the calls by .25s, but that's obviously not working. Then I get a few more 200 statuses back, then another 429, then a few 200s, then a couple more 429s, and then I get every PATCH request back returned with the status '422 Unprocessable Entry.' The response for these says Type: 'INVALID_VALUE_FOR_COLUMN', Message: 'Field (Checkbox field) can not accept value true'.

Help me out here? Really no clue where to go next. I'm totally open to scrapping this and learning what the heck node is to use the [official node.js client](https://github.com/airtable/airtable.js), if that's really where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Pretty simple way to deal with checkboxes I found works.

As for the Records situation yes Please use Node.js client and airtable.js npm package. Then use/build an API-proxy to produce a fetch of all records from the table depending on how large the Airtable is its self.

```
/* Checkbox
 * A single checkbox that can be checked or unchecked.
 * Parameters:
 *   name: <String>
 *   value: <Boolean>
 *     default: false
 *     Setting this field to 0, '0', undefined, or null will set it to false.
 *     Setting this field to 1 or '1' will set it to true.
 * Strict: value must be a Boolean. Numbers will throw an error.
 */

class Checkbox extends Field {
  constructor(name, value = false, config) {
    super(name, value, config);
    this.type = 'Checkbox';
  }

  /* get value
   * Return: <Boolean>
   *   Whether or not the checkbox is checked.
   */

  get value() {
    return this._value === true;
  }

  /* set value
   * Parameters:
   *   value: <Boolean>
   *     Whether or not the checkbox is checked.
   *     undefined or null will be set to false.
   *     '0' or 0 will be set to false.
   *     '1' or 1 will be set to true.
   */

  set value(value) {
    if (value === undefined || value === null)
      return this._value = false;
    if (this.isStrict && typeof value !== 'boolean')
      return this._error(`'value' must be a boolean.`, value);
    if (`${value}` === '0' || `${value}` === '1')
      value = !!Number(value);
    if (typeof value !== 'boolean')
      return this._error(`'value' must be a boolean.`, value);
    this._value = value;
  }
}

module.exports = Checkbox;
```